# Unable to successfully loop through imagss in a directory with PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here's the loop:

```
<?php
// I added this just to see if HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES points to the right directory
echo "<img style=\"width:100%;height:100%;\" src=\"" . HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES . "c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155/1.jpg\">\n";
// Loop through all the image files in the right sidebar.
foreach (glob(HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES . "c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155/{*.[gG][iI][fF],*.[jJ][pP][gG],*.[jJ][pP][eE][gG],*.[pP][nN][gG]}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image) {

    // Display the image in the right sidebar.
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-6 col-lg-4 item zoom-on-hover\">\n";
    echo "<a class=\"lightbox\" href=\"" . HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES . "c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155/" . basename($image) . "\">\n";
    echo "<img class=\"img-fluid image\" src=\"" . HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES . "c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155/" . basename($image) . "\" >\n";
    echo "</a>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}

?>
```

Here's the location of the pictures.php file where the loop is placed:
[image: location of the pictures.php file where I placed the foreach loop]

Here's the directory where the images are:
[image: images I want to loop through]

Edit:

Here's the definition of `HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES` as defined in `/bludit/bl-kernel/boot/init.php`:

```
$base = '';
if (!empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) && !empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) && empty($base)) {
    $base = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $base = dirname($base);
} elseif (empty($base)) {
    $base = empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $base = dirname($base);
}
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $base)!==0) {
    $base = '/';
} elseif ($base!=DS) {
    $base = trim($base, '/');
    $base = '/'.$base.'/';
} else {
    // Workaround for Windows Web Servers
    $base = '/';
} 

define('HTML_PATH_ROOT', $base);
define('HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES',        HTML_PATH_ROOT.'bl-content/uploads/pages/');
```

Comment: What's the value of `HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES`? `glob` expects a file path (or a pattern for it), while the `src` attribute of an image expects an URL/URI, which are different things.

Comment: I added the definition of `HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES`. Does that help @Jeto ? Hmm, the fact that `glob` expects a file path explains why the image gets displayed but the foreach loop doesn't work. What do I have to change to give glob a file path instead of an URL/URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this constant to get the filesystem path of your folder:

```
define('FILE_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES', 
  rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/\\') . '/bludit/bl-content/uploads/pages/');
```

Then use it with glob:

```
glob(FILE_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES . 'c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155 ...');
```

Alternative with a relative path:

```
define('FILE_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES', 
  __DIR__ . '/../../bl-content/uploads/pages/');
```

However, if you really don't want to create another constant at all, you can try:

```
glob(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/\\') 
  . '/' . HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES 
  .  'c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155...');
```

Comment: If this still doesn't work, please `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` and let me know its value. You basically have to build a path from there (though you could also use a relative path from your current script, but that's a bit awkward in your case imho).

Comment: I changed the constant `FILE_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES` to: `define('FILE_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES', 
  rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/\\') . '/bludit/bl-content/uploads/pages/');` and now it works. :D is there any way I can use the constant `HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES` which has a value of "/bludit/bl-content/uploads/pages/"?

Comment: What I had in mind was something like: `glob("../../../../" .HTML_PATH_UPLOADS_PAGES."c60fca4c682803c969f2410084878155 ...");

Comment: @Johnny See my edited answer. Again, I might be a few folders off, but by var_dumping the different elements you should find the right formula :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeto! Mind me buying you a B̶e̶e̶r̶ beverage of joice?

Comment: That's tempting (though, "joice", are you sure about that?...) Anyway, just marking the answer as accepted will do :)

Comment: LOL! Yeah it's `J`etos ch`oice` ;)